# How to return items based on a count

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return the most gifted items that belong to an `order` from the `orders` table. Currently this returns any item that has been gifted, what I'd like it to do is check that the item has been gifted more than once before returning it, as a way of checking that the gift isn't a one off and it's actually a popular gift choice.

This is what I have currently:

```
SELECT Item_Type, Item_Desc, item_Cost 
FROM rbickers.Item

LEFT join rbickers.Basket 
ON Item.Item_id = Basket.theItem_id

LEFT join rbickers.order
on basket.ord_ID = Order.order_ID

LEFT join rbickers.Session 
on Order.Session_id = Session.Ses_id 

WHERE Order.order_isGift = "true"
order by item_type
```

Comment: can you provide a schema

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: This is a graphical representation of my schema, I hope this helps. http://tinypic.com/r/102qjps/6

Comment: when you say gifted do you mean bought. what does gifted mean. thx

Comment: Hi, yeah sorry. No, it works similar to the Amazon gift service. If the item is selected as a gift it comes gift wrapped with no invoice in the actual item packaging etc.

Comment: so how to know if it is gifted based on your schema. i can be dense.

Comment: Oh, damn. Sorry that was from a previous version, in the new version everything is the same apart from that, it's 'Order_isGift' in the order table that hasn't been included but needs to be queried.

Comment: so lets say i have an order. i have 3 items in that order. item 1 qty 1 item 2 qty 2 item 3 qty 3. i find your schema confusing as how you achieve this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20032/discussion-between-drew-pierce-and-springfox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html) and HAVING:

```
SELECT Item_Type, Item_Desc, Item_Cost 
FROM Item
JOIN Basket ON theItem_id = Item_ID
JOIN Order ON Order_ID = Ord_ID
WHERE Order_isGift = "true"
GROUP BY Item_ID
HAVING count(1) > 1
```

Comment: This will work in MySQL, but when using `group by` you should make sure that all non-aggregated fields in the `select` clause is also used in the `group by` clause. Not every database engine is as forgiving as MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about having another table which simply counts the gifts as they are gifted?  You could then sort on `Times_Gifted`, and it would save some operations on the backend.

Otherwise, if it is a one off calculation, perhaps something like this

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `tablename`
```

with appropriate other filters for your needs (cribbed from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum the number of times each item has been gifted, order the results my largest count first, then take only the first row:

```
SELECT Item_Type, Item_Desc, item_Cost, sum(Basket.qty) as total_ordered
FROM rbickers.Item
LEFT join rbickers.Basket ON Item.Item_id = Basket.theItem_id
LEFT join rbickers.order on basket.ord_ID = Order.order_ID
LEFT join rbickers.Session on Order.Session_id = Session.Ses_id 
WHERE Order.order_isGift = "true"
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY sum(Basket.qty) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```